# If fill in field = Array than JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I created 3 array's for testing: "7681" "7682" "7683".
So I want if somebody fills in: "7681" in the fill in field than you get a message:

```
document.write('Wij bezorgen <b>wel</b> op uw adres!');
```

And else (if the fill in is not "7681" "7682" or "7683".you get te message

```
document.write('Wij bezorgen <b>niet</b> op uw adres!');
```

Now I have tested this. But it always gives the message that you filled in the array:

```
document.write('Wij bezorgen <b>wel</b> op uw adres!');
```

But thats not good. If I fill in for example: 1234 than it needs to activate the else function. And it is not doing it!

This is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Validate US Zip Code in JavaScript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function IsValidZipCode(zip) {
            var isValid = new Array();
            isValid[0] = "7681";
            isValid[1] = "7682";
            isValid[2] = "7683";
            if (isValid) {
                document.write('Wij bezorgen <b>wel</b> op uw adres!');
            }
            else {
                document.write('Wij bezorgen <b>niet</b> op uw adres!');
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>


<body>
<form>
<input id="txtZip" name="zip" type="text" /><br />
<input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Validate"
onclick="IsValidZipCode(this.form.zip.value)" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` conditions are not checking the input value.
You can use `indexOf` method of an array to check if the `zip` variable exists within the array.
Try this -

```
if (isValid.indexOf(zip) != -1) {
...Rest of your code...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a JS Beginner, so don't completely trust me on this. But your code says "if (isValid)". I think the problem is that web you type in a data type by itself in a conditional expression, JS checks if the variable is true or false. There probably is an error where it thinks that isValid is a Boolean value, and it executes the if clause, and never executes the else clause. You want it to check if the user's input is part of the array. (Hint: use indexOf). Hope I helped!

Comment: You're correct, this case will always evaluate the same.  But it doesn't have to be a boolean value.  JavaScript can check for ["truthy" and "falsy"](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).